# How Can I Render a Partial View via AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

This should be relatively simple for the MVC experts out there, but I'm still learning the ropes.

- I have a View which is not strongly-typed, simply `ViewPage<dynamic>`.
- On this View, I have a single textbox, which is extended using jQuery's AutoComplete
- When the user types something into the textbox, the AutoComplete does an AJAX call to a Controller, which calls a stored procedure, returning a JSON collection of records, with 2 properties:

  - **ID** (Identifer for the item)
  - **Name** (Name for the item)

Now, with the jQuery AutoComplete UI Plugin, when a user clicks one of the items that is shown in the autocomplete, a client-side event is called, passing through the JSON object:

```
// .. snip heaps of jQuery
select: function (event, ui) {
   // ui is a JSON object:
   //    ui.item.id
   //    ui.item.name
}
```

**Now my question is** - from this client-side event, I need to display on the same page (below the texbox), *extended* information about this item. (obviously will require another AJAX call to the server).

How can I do that? The only thing I can think of is simply make the jQuery call another controller which returns a single `JsonResult`, and manually parse this JSON, displaying the HTML I want.

Is that the only way? Is there a helper I can use? The reason my View is not strongly-typed is because when the page loads, there is no information displayed about the model, simply a textbox.

I was really hoping I could create a partial view that is strongly-typed, and somehow call RenderPartial on this partial view, passing through the id of the item I want to display. Is this possible from client-side/AJAX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=partial+view+ajax

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use jQuery to request html as well as Json from the controller.  So your jQuery could look like this:

```
$.get(action, null, function(data){
  $('#someDiv').html(data);
}, 'html');
```

and you controller could return:

```
return PartialView("SomePartial", Model)
```

And the html would be rendered to the screen

Comment: And specifically, 'action' in the jQuery snippet is a path to a controller action (using the ui.item.id).

Comment: BTW - what's the last parameter to `$.get`? ('html'). I left that out.

Comment: the last parameter tells jquery what sort of response to expect- valid arguements are 'json', 'html', 'xml' (maybe others).  Although in practice it seems you can leave it off an it will work fine.

Comment: One more thing i should point out-  IE will tend to cache $.get ajax requests so if you have partials that change a lot, use $.post (same syntax) to get around this limitation